# How to set default value to combo box in SWT before selecting

Tags: java, combobox, swt

```
Combo combo = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE);
combo.setText("session");
```

I want session to display as default value in combo box.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'default value'? Are you asking about the value shown in the text field or the items shown in the drop down list? Is this a read only or read/write combo? Show us how you created the combo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is not working in your case. Could you please provide a detailed code? I tried below code and it worked fine for me:

```
Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.NONE);
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        combo.add("AAA");
        combo.add("BBB");
        combo.add("CCC");
        combo.add("DDD");

        combo.setText("BBB");
```

Comment: Even if i have used the above code it is not displaying session as default value.                                                                                                           Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated my answer. setText() works fine.please check above code snippet